# Difference between window.AudioContext and navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, html5-audio, getusermedia

I've searched and read a few articles found through Google search, but can't find a laid out answer.

Besides initiation what is the difference between window.AudioContext and navigator.getUserMedia?

Also I already know getUserMedia can be used to also get camera stream, but this is more in the scope of audio. Browser support info would also be very helpful.

Comment: Found the browser support answer at [link](http://caniuse.com)

Answer (score 2):

getUserMedia() gets input data from microphones, camera or other locations (screencaptures (which will include audio capture soon), etc).  It creates a MediaStream (with one or more MediaStreamTracks).  You can also create MediaStreams from media elements (element.captureStream()/etc) or canvases (canvas.captureStream(...) - obviously video only).  Note that captureStream() is in the process of being incorporated into the specs for MediaStreams.

An AudioContext is the grouping construct for WebAudio graphs.  It isn't a source or even a processing node, it's a context (graph) the WebAudio code works in.  You can feed a MediaStream (the audio tracks thereof) into a WebAudio AudioContext, or use other recorded or synthetic inputs/generators.

Very different constructs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of difference between `window.AudioContext` and `navigator.getUserMedia`. [GetUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) gives you the audio stream generated in terms of a MediaStream object whereas [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) is used mainly in terms of audio-processing. You will also get the supported browsers in the provided links.

Comment: Encoding wise, does that mean the streams in the MediaStream object is encoded and that the stream from AudioContext is raw(Straight from the device)?

Comment: @Gerardlamo As far as I know AudioContext cannot create a stream rather it takes stream generated by GetUserMedia and creates MediaNodes using some [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource). The methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioContext#Methods) can give you a better idea.